# C++ putback() member function

Tags: c++

I am just a bit confused: the member function putback() puts back the last  character read back into the input stream. What does this mean exactly? I tried to experiment with it and I noticed no difference in the outcomes of the files whether I use putback() or not.

*I have two text files: input.txt with contents "5 2" and output.txt with no contents prior to operation.

e.g

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char next;

    ifstream fin;
    ofstream fout;

    fin.open("input.txt");
    fout.open("output.txt");


    if((fin.fail())||(fout.fail()))
    {
        cout<<"File failed to open files";
        return 1;
    }

    while(next!='2')
    {
        fin.get(next);
        fout.put(next);
    }
    fin.putback(next);

    cout<<"This is next:"<<next;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code appears to have no `putback` in it...

Comment: In order to see `putback` working, you have to write `putback`.

Comment: You also need to READ from the stream AFTER `putback` for it to have any effect. If you do `char other; fin.get(other); cout << "What we put back:" << other << endl;` or some similar, it would help a lot.

Comment: @mats Petersson,When i do that all that gets output is an address..

Comment: @Zibele: I very much doubt it. But perhaps you are doing something other than what my code shows?

Answer (score 1):

`putback` puts its parameter back into the input stream, making it the next character to be read.  To see it at work, change your loop to the following and watch the program enter an endless loop:

```
while (next != '2') {
    fin.get(next);
    fin.putback(next); // This will cause an infinite loop
    fout.put(next);
}
```

This happens because the very first `5` you read will be immediately put back into the input stream, causing `next` to never become `2`.

Answer (score 0):

> What does this mean exactly?

I think it means something like

- each character of a text file 'resides' at a certain 'position indicator' in the file (you may also have read about 'file offset').
- get() transfers a copy of the value at the current 'position', to your variable (called next), and then
- increments the 'position' indicator (i.e. simulates 'consumption' of the char)

Note that there is a buffer associated with 'ifstream fin'. fin handles lots of specifics that I think you don't want to worry about. For instance, what causes transfers (from the current 'position') some of the file contents from disk to the buffer (of fin) so that 'get()' knows where to find it.  How much of the file is buffered?  etc.

- putback() decrements the 'position' indicator,

Although this is probably too simple a description of all the stuff going on, the result is no change to the file.  The next get() will read the same char once again.

Now consider the test case where the user code puts back the last character of the previous full buffer; or the test case where the user code puts back the last n chars read.  Just be glad it is being done for you.

Your experiment is flawed. I hope the above helps you devise a better experiment.

I suggest you do a small number of get(), then use tellg to see if it changes for each get or putback.  Also, experiment with seekg.

Hope this helps.